# Does Linux typically log system temperature data?

Tags: linux, logs, hard-disk, cpu, temperature

Do mainstream Linux distributions typically log system temperature data, e.g. CPU or HDD temperature? If so, where can those logs be found?

Comment: No, unless the distro sees a benefit in doing this per default you'll have to set it up yourself. Ages ago I used rrdtool (as I didn't need long historic data) for this and I'm not surprised it is still being used for this. See a tutorial here: http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool-trac/wiki/SystemMonitorScripts

Comment: The question is very pertinent, as many SBC servers have temperature related issues.

Comment: No they do not; however it is pretty easy with `lm_sensors`  to either put monitoring on a terminal real-time or direct output to a log file. But you will need to set it up - that is easy; you even can set it up for multiple servers with minimum fuss. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lm_sensors#Automatic_lm_sensors_Deployment as well as: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6712

Comment: Thanks for all these comments. Thomas R. Koll and r0berts, feel free to post your helpful comments as answers instead. After all, answers can be upvoted for points!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not aware of a mainstream Linux distribution which logs this type of information by default. Most mainstream Linux distributions do include various packages which can log temperatures, and some of these packages are set up to log by default.

Taking Debian as an example, `sensord` will periodically log all the information it knows about (system temperatures, voltages etc.) to the system log, but it needs to be configured manually before it can log anything useful; `hddtemp` can be set up to periodically log hard drive temperatures. Many other tools can retrieve this type of information (using IPMI, SNMP, etc.) but again in most cases they need to be configured, either to be able to access the information in the first place, or to be able to interpret it, or both.

This configuration requirement means that it would be difficult to set up a generic distribution which logs temperatures by default in a meaningful way. (Most of the systems I've seen have at least one, invalid, monitoring entry which would set off alarms if it was auto-configured!) Of course it's entirely possible to set up an installer image for your own systems since you know what they are and how they're configured... Once you've configured the various tools required to extract temperature information, you'd be better off using a proper monitoring tool (such as [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)) to log the temperatures instead of relying on the system logs. That way you can also set up alerts to be notified when things start going wrong.

Expanding on the `sensord` example, you can find its output in the system log, with `sensord` as the process name; so either look for `sensord` in `/var/log/syslog` (by default), or run `journalctl -u sensord`. You'll see periodic logs like the following (I've removed the date and hostname):

```
sensord[2489]: Chip: acpitz-virtual-0
sensord[2489]: Adapter: Virtual device
sensord[2489]:   temp1: 27.8 C
sensord[2489]:   temp2: 29.8 C
sensord[2489]: Chip: coretemp-isa-0000
sensord[2489]: Adapter: ISA adapter
sensord[2489]:   Physical id 0: 33.0 C
sensord[2489]:   Core 0: 29.0 C
sensord[2489]:   Core 1: 30.0 C
sensord[2489]:   Core 2: 26.0 C
sensord[2489]:   Core 3: 29.0 C
sensord[2489]: Chip: nct6776-isa-0a30
sensord[2489]: Adapter: ISA adapter
sensord[2489]:   in0: +1.80 V (min = +1.60 V, max = +2.00 V)
sensord[2489]:   in1: +1.86 V (min = +1.55 V, max = +2.02 V)
sensord[2489]:   in2: +3.41 V (min = +2.90 V, max = +3.66 V)
sensord[2489]:   in3: +3.39 V (min = +2.83 V, max = +3.66 V)
sensord[2489]:   in4: +1.50 V (min = +1.12 V, max = +1.72 V)
sensord[2489]:   in5: +1.26 V (min = +1.07 V, max = +1.39 V)
sensord[2489]:   in6: +1.04 V (min = +0.80 V, max = +1.20 V)
sensord[2489]:   in7: +3.31 V (min = +2.90 V, max = +3.66 V)
sensord[2489]:   in8: +3.22 V (min = +2.50 V, max = +3.60 V)
sensord[2489]:   fan1: 1251 RPM (min = 200 RPM)
sensord[2489]:   fan2: 0 RPM (min = 0 RPM)
sensord[2489]:   fan3: 299 RPM (min = 200 RPM)
sensord[2489]:   fan4: 1315 RPM (min = 0 RPM)
sensord[2489]:   fan5: 628 RPM (min = 200 RPM)
sensord[2489]:   SYSTIN: 32.0 C (limit = 80.0 C, hysteresis = 70.0 C)
sensord[2489]:   CPUTIN: 33.0 C (limit = 85.0 C, hysteresis = 80.0 C)
sensord[2489]:   AUXTIN: 24.0 C (limit = 80.0 C, hysteresis = 75.0 C)
sensord[2489]:   PECI Agent 0: 31.0 C (limit = 95.0 C, hysteresis = 92.0 C)
sensord[2489]:   PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP: 57.0 C (limit = 95.0 C, hysteresis = 90.0 C)
sensord[2489]:   PCH_CHIP_TEMP: 0.0 C
sensord[2489]:   PCH_CPU_TEMP: 0.0 C
sensord[2489]:   beep_enable: Sound alarm enabled
sensord[2489]: Chip: jc42-i2c-9-18
sensord[2489]: Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 0580
sensord[2489]:   temp1: 32.8 C (min = 0.0 C, max = 60.0 C)
sensord[2489]: Chip: jc42-i2c-9-19
sensord[2489]: Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 0580
sensord[2489]:   temp1: 33.5 C (min = 0.0 C, max = 60.0 C)
sensord[2489]: Chip: jc42-i2c-9-1a
sensord[2489]: Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 0580
sensord[2489]:   temp1: 34.0 C (min = 0.0 C, max = 60.0 C)
sensord[2489]: Chip: jc42-i2c-9-1b
sensord[2489]: Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 0580
sensord[2489]:   temp1: 33.2 C (min = 0.0 C, max = 60.0 C)
```

To get this I had to determine which modules were needed (using `sensors-detect`): by default the system only knew about the ACPI-reported temperatures, which don't actually correspond to anything (they never vary). `coretemp` gives the CPU core temperatures on Intel processors, `nct6776` is the motherboard's hardware monitor, and `jc42` is the temperature monitor on the DIMMs. To make it useful for automated monitoring, I should at least disable the ACPI values and re-label the fans, and correct `fan4`'s minimum value. There are many other configuration possibilities, [`lm_sensors`' example configuration file](https://sources.debian.net/src/lm-sensors/1:3.4.0-2/etc/sensors.conf.eg/) gives some idea.

Comment: On Debian 10, I cannot find the `sensord.service` althouth the `lm-sensors` package is installed, how can I install the `sensord.service` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it was removed a year or so after I wrote this answer; see [#865042](https://bugs.debian.org/865042) for details. I still have the old package installed on my systems; I’ve been meaning to submit a patch to restore it in the `lm-sensors` source package, but haven’t got round to it yet (and since I haven’t done so in six years, I doubt I’ll do it any time soon, unless the package I currently have can no longer be kept installed).

Answer (score 3):

Some hard drives automatically keep a recent temperature history.  From `man smartctl`:

> scttemp,  scttempsts,  scttemphist  - [ATA only] prints the disk
>   temperature information provided by the SMART Command Transport (SCT)
>   commands.  The option ´scttempsts´ prints current temperature and
>   temperature ranges returned by the SCT Status command, ´scttemphist´
>   prints temperature limits and the temperature history table returned
>   by the SCT Data Table command, and ´scttemp´ prints both.  The
>   temperature values are preserved across power cycles.  The logging
>   interval can be configured  with the ´-l scttempint,N[,p]´ option, see
>   below.  The SCT commands were introduced in ATA8-ACS and were also
>   supported by many ATA-7 disks.

A command like `smartctl -data -l scttemphist /dev/sda` will give you a temperature history if the drive supports it.  For example:

```
Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
 103    2017-06-27 11:10    31  ************
 ...    ..( 24 skipped).    ..  ************
   0    2017-06-27 15:20    31  ************
   1    2017-06-27 15:30    30  ***********
 ...    ..(  9 skipped).    ..  ***********
  11    2017-06-27 17:10    30  ***********
  12    2017-06-27 17:20    31  ************
  13    2017-06-27 17:30    30  ***********
 ...    ..( 51 skipped).    ..  ***********
  65    2017-06-28 02:10    30  ***********
  66    2017-06-28 02:20    31  ************
  67    2017-06-28 02:30    32  *************
  68    2017-06-28 02:40    31  ************
  69    2017-06-28 02:50    30  ***********
  70    2017-06-28 03:00    31  ************
  71    2017-06-28 03:10    30  ***********
  72    2017-06-28 03:20    30  ***********
  73    2017-06-28 03:30    31  ************
  74    2017-06-28 03:40    30  ***********
  75    2017-06-28 03:50    31  ************
  76    2017-06-28 04:00    31  ************
  77    2017-06-28 04:10    30  ***********
 ...    ..( 22 skipped).    ..  ***********
 100    2017-06-28 08:00    30  ***********
 101    2017-06-28 08:10    31  ************
 102    2017-06-28 08:20    30  ***********
```

Other than that though, you will need to configure/install a tool (see Stephen Kitt's answer).

Answer (score 2):

I just found "psensor" monitor and I find it easy to use and handy: https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/

[image]